# Create MKMapView region out of MKPolyline

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkpolyline

#### Background:

I need to make region out of a `MKPolyline` overlay. The region should be just as big as the GPS track.

#### Problem:

I cant use `showAnnotations` since its an overlay, not annotations:

```
  mapView.showAnnotations(mapView.annotations, animated: true)
```

How to I achieve the same result but with `MKPolyline`?

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```
var points:[CLLocationCoordinate2D] = self.track.getCLLocationCoordinate2D()
let polylines = MKPolyline(coordinates: &points, count: points.count)
let rect = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(polylines.boundingMapRect)
self.trackMapView.addOverlay(polylines)
self.trackMapView.setRegion(rect, animated: true)
```